# Ruby On Rails - AJAX Call, Template Missing [edit - rendering html instead of js ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

**Context** - I have a web page, that says upload file. The file has questions in JSON format. When the file is uploaded, the questions should be inserted into a particular table. Once done, the page should show how many questions inserted and how many errored out.

**Error**: On uploading the file, I get a message - Template Missing

> Missing template questions/upload_questions, application/upload_questions with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/tusharsaurabh/Ruby On Rails/Q/app/views"

I have checked the "Views" folder and the template is present.

**Issue** - 
How to resolve the Template Missing issue, even though it is present?

**EDIT**
The application is searching for upload_questions.html.erb instead of upload_qustions.js.erb. How do I make the app render js.erb template instead of html.erb.

**Code Snippets**

View that shows the upload question button. **show_upload_screen.html.erb**

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin:20% 30% 30% 30%;background: linear-gradient(15deg, #ff471a, #ffff00);border-radius:10px;display:flex;">

<%= form_tag '/questions/upload_questions',multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= file_field_tag "file",id:"file_tag", type: "hidden",class: "btn btn-primary control-label col-md-8"  %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Process',id:"submit_tag",class: "btn btn-primary control-label col-md-4" %>

  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="well" id="show_uploaded_question_summary" style="margin-top:10px;display:none">
  <ul>
    <li>Number of Question Updated <%=@updated_questions%></li>
    <li>Number of Question Failed <%=@errored_questions%></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
root 'signup#validate'
post "/signup/verify" => 'signup#verify'
get "/signup/verify" => 'signup#verify'

get "/questions_controller/show_question" => "questions#show_question"
get "/questions_controller/check_answers" => "questions#check_answers"
get "/signup/create_user" => 'signup#create_user'
post "/signup/create_user" => 'authenticates#create_user'
get "/questions/show_upload_screen" => 'questions#show_upload_screen'
post "/questions/upload_questions" => 'questions#upload_questions'
```

questions_controller.rb

```
  def upload_questions

    @errored_questions = 0
    @updated_questions = 0
    tempfl = params[:file]

    question_array = JSON.parse(tempfl.tempfile.read)

    question_array.each do |question_hash|
      logger.debug "the hash i am trying is #{question_hash}"
      id_rel = Title.get_title_id(question_hash["title"])
      if id_rel.nil? 
        id = Title.insert_title(question_hash["title"])
      else
        id = id_rel.id
      end
      question_updated = Title.update_questions(id, question_hash)
      logger.debug "the return is #{question_updated}"
      if question_updated == "Not Saved"
        @errored_questions += 1
      else
        @updated_questions += 1
      end
    end
    logger.debug "the data value is #{@errored_questions} #{@updated_questions}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'upload_questions.js.erb' }
      format.html
    end
  end
```

The models are, Title - questions has been categorized in different bucket. Each bucket is called Title. Question - individual questions.

**Title**

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions

  def self.get_all_title
    title_all = Title.all
  end

  def self.get_title_id title_name
    title_rel = Title.find_by title: title_name
  end

  def self.insert_title title_name
    title_rec = Title.create(title: title_name)
  end

  def self.update_questions id, my_hash
    title = Title.find id
    title.questions.create(question: my_hash["question"],option1: my_hash["options"][0],option2: my_hash["options"][1],option3: my_hash["options"][2],option4: my_hash["options"][3],answer: my_hash["answer"])

  rescue => e
    logger.debug "Error: Creating the data #{my_hash} #{e.full_messages}"
    return "Not Saved"
  end
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :title

  def self.get_saved_answer(question_id)
    result = Question.find_by id: question_id
    result['answer']
  end
end
```

**upload_questions.js.erb**

```
$('#show_uploaded_question_summary').css('display','inline');
```

Log Output
[image]

Snapshot of Rails folder -

[image]

Comment: You can create a view that has the required name or you can change your 'format.html' response to go to a different page.  What's your goal after a file is uploaded?   Basically the default rails response to a controller action is to look for a view of the same name unless told otherwise.

Comment: @MageeWorld in the show_upload_screen.html.erb, there is an element that has "display:none;" property. Once the file has been uploaded, the upload_questions.js.erb will just make the css property inline. thats all. The file upload_questions.js.erb is present in view folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit the form you are making a `POST` request to the `questions/upload_questions` route which runs the `QuestionsController#upload_questions` action as you expect.

**The problem is that this action is being requested with an `HTML` format** which is the default and would result in Rails trying to render an `upload_questions.html.erb` template.

Since your intention is to render a *JavaScript* response in the form of the `upload_questions.js.erb` template, **you need to request the route with the JS format**.

To do this, you need to include the `remote: true` option on your form. This tells Rails to request a `JS` format response rather than an `HTML` one.

```
<%= form_tag '/questions/upload_questions', remote: true, multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" do %>
```